# How to remove the last character from a char string, which is in an array of char strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

So, I've been trying to remove the last character from a string, which is a located in an array of strings. I've done some searching and haven't had any luck finding a solution. I've tried implementations where I memcpy or strcpy n-1 bytes but they haven't worked out.

Here is the gist of what i'm trying to do

```
char *array[3];
array[0] = "avg:";
```

I want to create a new char array and have it hold "avg".

I thought i'd be able to do something like this,

```
char *array[3];
array[0] = "avg:";

char new[sizeof(array[0])-1];
strncpy(new,array[0],sizeof(new));
```

But that gives some funky output, ie "avg¤ã@À‡¿". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sizeof(array[0])` --> `strlen(array[0])`. And you need to NUL terminate `new` after the `strncpy`.

Comment: `char new[strlen(array[0])]; memcpy(new, array[0], sizeof(new)); new[sizeof(new)-1] = 0;`

Comment: Ah ok, I was on the right track, just getting confused between the use of strlen and sizeof. This did exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that `array[0]` is a pointer.  A `char *`.  So `sizeof(array[0])` is the size of a pointer, not the size of what the pointers points to.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't terminate your copy properly, your string should always terminate with '\0'.

I would do:

```
char *array[3];
array[0] = "avg:";

char *new = (char *) calloc(strlen(array[0]),sizeof(char));
strncpy(new,array[0],strlen(array[0])-1);
```

Because memory allocation will always allocate empty memory for your char array.

Make sure you `free(new)` before leaving your scope.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fixed

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm pretty sure new and array[0] has identical size, so there's no overflow.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY fixed. I know what you mean. `calloc` here initialize the `new` to be `\0\0\0\0`,  but array[0] was `avg:\0`, so it kinda does the job, not sure why there's no complaint in compiler.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, now it's `calloc(strlen(array[0])+1, sizeof(char))`, and when I copy, I copy with `strlen(array[0])`,according to man page: "The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.  The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied."

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fixed

Comment: Corner case: If `array[0] = "";` then `strncpy(..., ...,strlen(array[0])-1);` might take a while to complete (or fail).

Comment: @chux You are right, but for his case, my answer is enough.